# How to show corresponding value of a calculated field through html query string to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a shopping cart functionality which allows users to add items to a shopping cart(via a add to cart button.) I have a specials page where members get discounted price for items. i have successfully passed the id(database) and sales price (calculated value) from the specials page to a add to cart page.

I couldnt post images because i dont have reputations so here is what the url looks like:

```
http://localhost:51231/LegoBits/Shopping/ShoppingCartItem.aspx?Id=1&SalesPrice=0.89
```

You can see the url is getting the values Id and SalesPrice from another page, but , i'm having trouble showing the salesPrice value in datalist of current page.

here is my code for the shoppingCartItem.aspx

```
      <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" DataKeyField="Id" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">

    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Thumbnail", "{0}") %>' />
        <asp:Label ID="PictureURLLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval ("Thumbnail") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        <br />

        <strong style="text-align: left;">Name: </strong>
        <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
        <br />
        <strong style="text-align: left;">Model: </strong>
        <asp:Label ID="ModelLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Model") %>'></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <strong style="text-align: left;">Ages: </strong>
        <asp:Label ID="AgesLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Ages") %>'></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <strong style="text-align: left;">Price: </strong>
        $
        <asp:Label ID="PriceLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
       <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="../Images/AddToCart.jpg"  ID="Button1"  runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

and its code behind:

```
public partial class Shopping_ShoppingCartItem : BasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string salePrice = Request.QueryString["Sales Price"];
        string price = Request.QueryString["price"];


        if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Member"))
        {

                 ((Label)DataList1.Controls[0].FindControl("PriceLabel")).Text = salePrice;
        }
        else {
            ((Label)DataList1.Controls[0].FindControl("PriceLabel")).Text = price;
        }

    }
```

The priceLabel should show the SalesPrice value passed as querystring from another page. Please help me out. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: One immediate thing I see is that when you try getting the SalesPrice you have a space char in `Request.QueryString["Sales Price"];` but not in your url's querystring `&SalesPrice=0.89`.

Comment: @LGSon absolutely with u on this. Query String here you need to pass without space

Comment: I realized and tried it as SalesPrice, it gave me $ only, like the labeltext was empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

**ASPX**

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" DataKeyField="ID" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="PriceLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
protected void Page_Load(object source, System.EventArgs e)
{ 
    dynamic data = new[] {
        new { ID = 1, Name ="Name_1"} 
    };
    DataList1.DataSource = data;
    DataList1.DataBind();
}
protected void Page_PreRender(object source, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string salePrice = Request.QueryString["SalesPrice"];

    ((Label)DataList1.Controls[0].FindControl("PriceLabel")).Text = salePrice;
}
```

**Update 1**

**ASPX**

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" DataKeyField="ID" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="PriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SalesPrice") %>' ></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
protected void Page_Load(object source, System.EventArgs e)
{


    dynamic data = new[] {
new { ID = 1, Name ="Name_1", SalesPrice = 10.00}
};
    DataList1.DataSource = data;
    DataList1.DataBind();
}
protected void Page_PreRender(object source, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["SalesPrice"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["SalesPrice"]))
    {
        string salePrice = Request.QueryString["SalesPrice"];
        ((Label)DataList1.Controls[0].FindControl("PriceLabel")).Text = salePrice;
    }
}
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: this worked and showed the value but i have a small issue...  my condition is like this,

there are 3 roles: member, dealer and admin

anonymous users have 2 pages with the price linked to database


while the 3 roles have specials pages which offers them discounts like 10% to member and 15 % to admin and dealer,

so the SalesPrice here is a calculated value (Price*discount)

my issue now is if i do as u posted, it will show salesPrice but when i try to add item from anonymous users, it doesnt show the orignal price. can u think of any way to solve this?? thanx heaps already

Comment: yup, and i tried myself to fix this, then i came to realise its not abt roles, the condition is 

if the passed query string is price then label text should be price or else if salesPrice is passed then label should be salesPrice.... how do i include that in a condition??? sorry for misleading u to a different result, im a beginner so struggling with this minor things

Comment: I have added new code under "update 1" in above answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the space.

```
 string salePrice = Request.QueryString["SalesPrice"];
```